# Friends of Friends/2nd degree friend's list. Facebook Graph API

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of my friend's friends using the iPhone Facebook SDK.
I've tried an approach using FQL and the Graph API but I get an error in both cases:

> "Can't lookup all friends of YYYYYY. Can only lookup for the logged in user (XXXXX), or
>       friends of the logged in user with the appropriate permission"

I've done some research and see that this functionality wasn't available through the Facebook API up until October 2010. But then radio silence. Well, it's almost 6 months later. So was this ever implemented?

I have requested all permissions I need for my app as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality does not exist in the Facebook Social Graph API or the FQL API.

During my quest to find out how to accomplish this I found many developers who asked the same question. Some developers have been asking for this feature for over 2 years. I think the FB team may consider it a privacy of performance concern.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on it. I was able to see friends of my friend.

It needs following requirements:

1. Your friend needs to be using application.
2. Permission from application read_stream, publish_stream, publish_checkins.

Try this fql query.

```
$query="SELECT uid, name, work_history FROM user 
      WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 IN 
      ( SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN 
         (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $fb_id ) and is_app_user=1)
       )";
```

Comment: This has always been the case - you can only fetch 'friends of friends' of a friend which already uses the same app

Comment: @Igy: Yeah... That's what I am saying in point 1... Anything wrong with my answer... You are hero of all facebook developers... I would love to listen if there are any mistakes. I can learn from it....